# google app script date parse is get wrong

Tags: google-apps-script

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var dataa = ss.getSheetByName("123").getRange("C1").getValue();
// C1 => 18:34:00.000
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(dataa, "GMT", "HH:mm"));
//Log =>[20-01-24 17:31:02:475 JST] 10:06
```

I bring the date of the spread sheet.

It was expressed as a google app script date.

However, the results are different.

Why is this like this?

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to do  with the dates?

Comment: The date is from 1 timezone and you're formatting it to another it seems. Check your spreadsheet & script timezones.

Comment: Karan // i want do compare date

Comment: ross // yes but. hour time can change in timezone. but minute time why is diffrent?

Comment: You might not need to format for comparison purposes. Also as ross said, the timezone of your spreadsheet is most likely different from GMT

Comment: @cloudbabby Please show us what the value in C1 looks like in the spreadsheet. That output looks like duration, not datetime.

Comment: Diego // yes i update in post , img => https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmFm8.png

Comment: Diego// ok i understand that. one more thing i have database two date filed  A : [yyyy-mm-dd] B : [ hh-mm] like as C1  ,   i compare date time first , and i want compare hourtime //  if(date >comparedate ) {  if(hour > comparehour){ do some}}  , date compare is fine, so how can i do hour time compare? not change database

Comment: If the format is always the same hh:mm:ss then you can split them as a  string on : and compare the resulting array values: [hh,mm,ss]. Also convert them to numbers first using array.map

Comment: Karan// ok thanks to answer can you answer this post? i want close it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're facing is with [`.getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue), which will parse the data in the cell into whatever Google thinks it is. To get the value exactly as you see it in the spreadsheet, use [`.getDisplayValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue).

Assuming that the values in column C are always in the same format (HH:mm:ss), you can simply split the value using the colon as delimiter and then compare these values against your control. (Take a look at the various [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) methods to compare against [hours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours), [minutes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMinutes), etc.)

```
var range = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("C1"); // 18:34:00
var displayValue = range.getDisplayValue();
var displayValueParts = displayValue.split(":");
var hour = displayValueParts[0];
var minutes = displayValueParts[1];
var seconds = displayValueParts[2]
```

Note here that just using `.getValue()`, Google interprets the value in C1 as a date.

```
var range = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("C1"); // 18:34:00
var value = range.getValue();
Logger.log(value); // Sat Dec 30 11:51:56 GMT+00:00 1899
```